# What is wrong with my charge-transfer balancing circuit for a Li-ion battery?

Tags: pwm, lithium-ion, resonance, cell-balancing

I am trying to simulate this balancing circuit.

[image]

The two complementary pulses control MOSFETs and as the resonant tank works the capacitors(as batteries) start to balance and I used op-amps to measure each cell balance (I know it is not ideal way to measure each cell). At first I used ideal switches and two capacitors as batteries and after finding out it works I used MOSFETs instead and added third capacitor and it also worked (although there were some problems regarding resonant tank's inductor and capacitor values). But obviously I did something wrong that the battery voltage started to decrease sharply when the second pulse goes up (I added 1 us deadtime between) as in the picture:

[image]
]

Then I undo the changes to the circuit(below picture) to see if there is a problem with MOSFETs and resonant tank but the problem persists even with this simple circuit. I have made changes to PWM but it just doesnt even care.

[image]

I want to know what could be the problem. And also the first circuit above has the same problem.
And I'd be grateful if you could help and share your thoughts, thank you.

Comment: If you use complementary drive signals you toggle between both MOSFET of a cell off and both MOSFET on, which is a shortcut across the cell. You need the same phase just with short deadtimes because one is a PFET and one is a NFET. Check the used schematic symbols in the diagram, they look wrong but this may be a pixel resolution problem.

Comment: But what about ideal switches? they don't work either.

Comment: Batteries don't behave much like capacitors, certainly not ones as miniscule as 100 uF.

Answer (score 2):

The most fundamental problem with your circuit is that it exists at all, because you can buy a Li-ion BMS IC that does balancing effectively, and reliably. There is need to proceed with your home-spun solution.

The second problem is that it is attempting to implement charge-transfer balancing ("active") instead of the simpler, more reliable, most effective in general applications solution: bypass balancing ("passive").

The third problem is that it is attempting to implement the "bucket brigade" topology, which is the second worst* topology for charge transfer balancing because, to transfer energy from one end of the string to the other end, by the time the charge gets to its intended destination, the inefficiency in the DC-DC converters causes all the original energy to be dissipated in heat an each step. That means that there is no advantage compared to bypass balancing. At the cost of needless complexity.

The fourth problem is that capacitor in series with the inductor (C8, C9) which prevents the energy storage in the inductor when DC is applied to it. I know you're trying to do a resonant tank, but that's going even further down the wrong rabbit hole.

The fifth problem is that all the MOSFETs are controlled together, preventing you from balancing a specific cell. It prevents you from selecting whether charge is steer up to the next cell above, or down to the next cell below.

The sixth problem is the capacitive coupling to the MOSFETs. Current spikes during use cause the cell voltages to jump, which in turn will turn on the MOSFETs unexpectedly.

The seventh problem is that the differential amplifiers on the left will drain your battery in days. And there's not a damn thing that the BMS can do to stop it.

The eight... Never mind, just buy a BMS IC and be done with it.

(*) The worst topology is capacitive balancing.

Comment: I know there are a lot of problems with it but it is one of the most used active balancing techniques. I know there are a bunch of IC that does the work but it is not my concern. It is for academic purposes. And I also know that many common electronic circuits do have IC equivalents but so what? I want to learn how it works and my main concern is to find what could be the solution to the problem. It is like 1st grade asking the teacher "why don't we use the calculator to solve these basic math problems instead of solving by hand" and we all know the answer.

Comment: Problem is problem, so if you don’t know how to solve then don’t answer at all.

Comment: @Shamurov I _DO_ know how to solve it and I _DID_ tell you how: "buy a Li-ion BMS IC that does balancing effectively, and reliably". It makes no sense in spending resources working on problems that have already been solved.

Comment: I see at least one good reason for active balancing: In some PV or wind driven charging systems the battery often does not reach the final charging phase, where passive balancers start to work, before a discharge phase starts again. In such a context the cells drift apart because the rare balancing phases cannot establish the balance in time. However, I like to use simple PWM driven half leg stages with one inductor in each leg to transfer the energy.